# Installing perl module without sudo access

Tags: linux, installation, perl-module, geoip

The module in question is [Geo::IP::PurePerl](http://search.cpan.org/~borisz/Geo-IP-PurePerl-1.25/lib/Geo/IP/PurePerl.pm) and this is what I'm doing:

```
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/B/BO/BORISZ/Geo-IP-PurePerl-1.24.tar.gz
tar -zxf Geo-IP-PurePerl-1.24.tar.gz
cd Geo-IP-PurePerl-1.24
perl Makefile.PL
make
make test
sudo make install
```

However, I don't have sudo access and just `make install` results in the following error:

```
[~/perl/Geo-IP-PurePerl-1.24]# make install
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
ERROR: Can't create '/usr/bin'
Do not have write permissions on '/usr/bin'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
 at -e line 1
make: *** [pure_site_install] Error 13
```

Is there any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there is any way to install a Perl module to the native system installation of Perl.

In the past I have had to install a new, completely independent version of perl in a directory that I do have write permission over and then ensure that my .profile file links my path to that location. Then whenever I call perl I'm accessing the local install area where I have full write access to.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=~/perllib`

of course then you will have to add that path to your `@INC` include path...